# Custom React Native UI Component: Invariant Violation

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, google-maps, react-native

I have built a custom React Native UI component following the documentation. The idea is that it will be an implementation of the Google Maps iOS API but for now it's just meant to show a standard Apple map.

I've built a new module using the command `react-native new-library GoogleMapView`. This added all the module files to `/Libraries/GoogleMapView/`.

I have file called `GoogleMapViewManager.h` which contains:

```
#import "RCTViewManager.h"

@interface GoogleMapManager : RCTViewManager

@end
```

The `GoogleMapManager.m` file contains:

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import "GoogleMapManager.h"

@implementation GoogleMapManager

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()

- (UIView *)view
{
    return [[MKMapView alloc] init];
}

@end
```

This is apparently the bare minimum required to get the map to show according to the docs. This does build and the app starts just fine.

On the JavaScript side of things, I have a file called `GoogleMapView.js` which contains:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var { requireNativeComponent } = React;

class GoogleMapView extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <GoogleMap {...this.props} />;
    }
}

GoogleMapView.propTypes = {
    //
};

var GoogleMap = requireNativeComponent('GoogleMap', GoogleMapView);

module.exports = GoogleMapView;
```

Again, this is more or less lifted from the docs so I'd expect it to work unless I've made a mistake somewhere.

When I try to do anything with this module, like include it in a file like so:

```
var React = require('react-native'), {Component, View, StyleSheet, GoogleMap} = React;
```

And then make use of it in a JSX view a bit like this (this is from my Map.js component):

```
render: function() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.flexContainer}>
            <GoogleMap/>
        </View>
    );
}
```

I get an 'Invariant Violation' error. I'm not too sure what this means, the full stack trace says this:

```
localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle
line: 2041
message: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. Check the render method of `Map`.'
2015-10-17 22:06:05.289 [warn][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] 'devtools socket closed'
```

Is there anything I've messed up here as I haven't been able to get past this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JavaScript require was incorrect, I needed to use:

```
var GoogleMap = require('../Libraries/GoogleMapView/GoogleMapView.js');
```

Rather than trying to bundle it all in with the React require:

```
var React = require('react-native'), {Component, View, StyleSheet, GoogleMap} = React;
```

Comment: Nice catch, but why is that? Is there a rule for what goes in the React catch all and what goes as a separate `require` line?

Comment: d'uh. this was my problem. thanks. @zipzit afaik, the React line is for React's own components, the requires for third party components.